# Content decoding issue when connecting REST with http

Tags: apache-camel

I am attempting to bridge a REST route to an upstream http service. There is an issue with decoding content - ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED when viewed from chrome. I assume this is gzip related. I am new to apache camel, so I am not sure where I went wrong.

Here's the route:

```
class RestRouteBuilder : RouteBuilder() {

    override fun configure() {
        restConfiguration().apply {
            component = "undertow"
            bindingMode = RestBindingMode.json
            port = "8082"
            scheme = "http"
        }

        rest("/airlines")
            .get("/").produces("application/json").to("undertow:http://localhost:8080/airlines?bridgeEndpoint=true")
    }
}
```

How would I return the content from the service on 8080 successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more reading and discovered that I was using **bindingMode** improperly. The 'Binding to POJOs' section of https://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html should explain everything for any newcomers with this same issue. In my particular case, the fix was simply to remove **bindingMode** from the rest configuration. This is safe in my example because I have no incoming message required to be unmarshalled - all GETs.

Working code:

```
class RestRouteBuilder : RouteBuilder() {

    override fun configure() {
        restConfiguration().apply {
            component = "undertow"
            port = "8082"
            scheme = "http"
        }

        rest("/airlines")
            .get("/").produces("application/json").to("undertow:http://localhost:8080/airlines?bridgeEndpoint=true")
    }
}
```